# Unable To Find Transaction Outpoint

Tags: transactions, utxo

I'm working on a project that involves constructing raw transactions and signing them locally before pushing to the network. I keep getting `Unable To Find Transaction Outpoint 1a67415e9f892c31cdaec29f6bf7e8e7ffd5a7cdca52fc565ad345313f85b222:90463999`.

Here's my tx hash

```
010000000122b2853f3145d35a56fc52cacda7d5ffe7e8f76b9fc2aecd312c899f5e41671aff5e64058a473044022052576f11b965d4b0a712b91e04377e25acebfad8093f3296deecb05ad429281502201ede7fb35f495985bb67d302465c6419fc1c683d26f7111d4e70cceac2dc86910141047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080ffffffff0101000000000000001976a914221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd488ac00000000
```

which decodes to

```
{
   "lock_time":0,
   "size":223,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "prev_out":{
            "index":90463999,
            "hash":"1a67415e9f892c31cdaec29f6bf7e8e7ffd5a7cdca52fc565ad345313f85b222"
         },
         "script":"473044022052576f11b965d4b0a712b91e04377e25acebfad8093f3296deecb05ad429281502201ede7fb35f495985bb67d302465c6419fc1c683d26f7111d4e70cceac2dc86910141047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080"
      }
   ],
   "version":1,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"a1981a142ba4966939d27e2cb78ae0a4d9550c91448105defdbed7ec71f2b351",
   "vout_sz":1,
   "out":[
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd4 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"147BM4WmH17PPxhiH1kyNppWuyCAwn3Jm4",
         "value":1,
         "script":"76a914221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd488ac"
      }
   ]
}
```

which seems to match the unspent ountput I see here: https://blockchain.info/unspent?address=1LCrg6DSqbcK5vh7XRAGEQA4jBpNigjwyV

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for "vout" is invalid. The source transaction only has three, not 90464000.

```
 "vout": 90463999,
```

The real output you are trying to spend is `0`. You confused `tx_index` and `tx_output_n`.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this solved the issue but I ran into a new one http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38051/op-equalverify-non-equal-data