# OP_EQUALVERIFY: non-equal data

Tags: protocol, raw-transaction, utxo

I'm trying to push the following transaction but keep getting `OP_EQUALVERIFY: non-equal data`

Here's the transaction

```
010000000122b2853f3145d35a56fc52cacda7d5ffe7e8f76b9fc2aecd312c899f5e41671a000000008c493046022100e484f5550ced311af2efb111237a54d0d93e68ac03ed5d084c669ae69afc36c902210087e69ce39c91936a4ec6fd66fb3b98d920a5ce4c3660a5519f9aa802787b09bb0141047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080ffffffff0101000000000000001976a914221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd488ac00000000
```

And here it is decoded

```
{
   "lock_time":0,
   "size":225,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "prev_out":{
            "index":0,
            "hash":"1a67415e9f892c31cdaec29f6bf7e8e7ffd5a7cdca52fc565ad345313f85b222"
         },
         "script":"493046022100e484f5550ced311af2efb111237a54d0d93e68ac03ed5d084c669ae69afc36c902210087e69ce39c91936a4ec6fd66fb3b98d920a5ce4c3660a5519f9aa802787b09bb0141047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080"
      }
   ],
   "version":1,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"fff4294e225832d1649f244b1a93651126b1f92b3f5eaf03500ea38bb9a6127b",
   "vout_sz":1,
   "out":[
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd4 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"147BM4WmH17PPxhiH1kyNppWuyCAwn3Jm4",
         "value":1,
         "script":"76a914221382696ab041ff0bce2aceeea15132d9336fd488ac"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your `value` is also incorrect, this transaction if valid would destroy your money into fees. Use the testnet for experimenting with Bitcoin or you have a very high risk of losing your money.

Answer (score 3):

This particular error message on bc.i means that the transaction is invalid due to OP_EQUALVERIFY operation failed

scriptSig is:

```
493046022100e484f5550ced311af2efb111237a54d0d93e68ac03ed5d084c669ae69afc36c902210087e69ce39c91936a4ec6fd66fb3b98d920a5ce4c3660a5519f9aa802787b09bb01
41047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080
```

So the public key is:

```
047920bd57b7b0dbf7ac242879ee1f1c4b87cbe30a1c31baa4d111850865042415d84f0a433174b3b17f41e280bfef85ff885dd8a1f25bf0823cfd77ec81bfc080
```

This is `uncompressed` public key and its address is `1Lj3WeRAmyN98jyiWE6AtnMKfzUzrPUL9z`

But `1a67415e9f892c31cdaec29f6bf7e8e7ffd5a7cdca52fc565ad345313f85b222:0` sends bitcoins to the another address: `1LCrg6DSqbcK5vh7XRAGEQA4jBpNigjwyV`

Are you sure that you use uncompressed public key instead of compressed one?

Comment: So I'm using bitcoinlib-js to build the transactions for me. I don't actually set the public key, they derive it from my public key. I'll look into this though.

Comment: Can I ask how you derived the public key from the scriptSig please- i cannot find a way how to do it

Comment: Peter, scriptSig for p2pkh-outputs has very simple structure: two push operations. First push is signature+hashtype. Second push is pubkey.